# Cross out node in chain in tikzpicture keeping boarder

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you please help me on how to cross out a node in a diagram with rectangular, framed nodes, ordered from left to right, connected by arrows? When using `cross out`, the frame/boarder lines vanish.

E.g., in the following graph, I would like to cross out the second node.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
    {
        arrows.meta,
        chains,
        shapes
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
            node distance = 15mm,
            start chain = going right,
            default/.style = {draw, minimum height = 10mm, minimum width = 15mm, align=center, font=\linespread{0.8}\selectfont}
        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain, join=by -Stealth}]
        \node (n1) [default]    {1};
        \node (n2) [default, cross out] {2};
        \node (n3) [default]    {3};
        \node (n4) [default]    {4};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun. The example below provides a new shape `framed cross out`, which will draw a cross out and its rectangular frame. It is implemented simply by copying the declaration of shape `cross out` and adding line `\inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]`.

```tex
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
    {
        arrows.meta,
        chains,
        shapes
    }

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{framed cross out}
{%
  % codes from shepe "cross out"
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]% % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}%
  
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle] %% <<< added
  
  \foregroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
 }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
            node distance = 15mm,
            start chain = going right,
            default/.style = {draw, minimum height = 10mm, minimum width = 15mm, align=center, font=\linespread{0.8}\selectfont}
        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain, join=by -Stealth}]
        \node (n1) [default]    {1};
        \node (n2) [default, framed cross out] {2};
        \node (n3) [default]    {3};
        \node (n4) [default]    {4};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much indeed - it not only solves the problem, but also is instructive regarding the general workings of tikz, which are, obviously, new to me. The enormous effort of this answer is breathtaking for me.

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `fit` library for draw `cross out` after drawing main node:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
    {
        arrows.meta,
        chains,
        fit,
        shapes
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]%, t
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    node distance = 15mm,
    start chain = going right,
    default/.style = {draw, minimum height = 10mm, minimum width = 15mm, 
                      align=center, font=\linespread{0.8}\selectfont},
    fco/.style = {draw, inner sep=0pt, cross out, fit=#1}, %Fit, Cross Out
    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={default, on chain, join=by -Stealth}]
        \node (n1)  {1};
        \node (n2)  {2};
        \node (n3)  {3};
        \node (n4)  {4};
    \end{scope}
    \node[fco=(n2)]  {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** solution with the use of the `path picture bounding box`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
    {
        arrows.meta,
        chains,
    }
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box} % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]%, t
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    node distance = 15mm,
      start chain = going right,
       box/.style = {draw, minimum height = 10mm, minimum width = 15mm, 
                     align=center, font=\linespread{0.8}\selectfont},
        co/.style = {box, % crossed out
                     path picture={\draw (\ppbb.north west) -- (\ppbb.south east)
                                         (\ppbb.south west) -- (\ppbb.north east);} % <---
                      }
    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={box, on chain, join=by -Stealth}]
        \node (n1)  {1};
        \node (n2) [co] {2}; % <---
        \node (n3)  {3};
        \node (n4)  {4};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much; it completely solves my issues and implementing your first solution, together with \uncover<a-b>{x}, I could also easily implement my "animation" (incrementally uncovering and crossing out).